# Why does xpath find <ul> and <p> but not <div>?

Tags: html, xpath

Given the following html:

```
<div>
    <h4>some text</h4>
    <div>
        <ul></ul>
        <div></div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

These two xpaths find 1 node each:

```
//h4[contains(text(), 'some text')]/following-sibling::div/ul
//h4[contains(text(), 'some text')]/following-sibling::div/p
```

But this one returns 0 finds.

```
//h4[contains(text(), 'some text')]/following-sibling::div/div
```

Why doesn't the third xpath also return 1 find?

Comment: Where/How did you run the XPath? The third XPath returned 1 result for me, as expected : http://xpatheval.apphb.com/p_klroKSS

Comment: @har07. I hadn't know about that website, thanks. I've just run a check on the selenium WebDriver that I was using. I had been using an HtmlUnitDriver but when I changed this to a FirefoxDriver, the div element was found. I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

When I disabled javascript for the webpage that I was looking at, the HTML of the page changed. This solved the issue for me. Thanks to @Sebastian Zartner for this:

[How can I get Firebug to match HtmlUnitDriver's pageSource report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190327/how-can-i-get-firebug-to-match-htmlunitdrivers-pagesource-report)