# How can I get Firebug to match HtmlUnitDriver's pageSource report?

Tags: java, html, selenium, firebug, headless-browser

I'm using Java with the Selenium Library to scrape a webpage. When I use Firebug on the page in Firefox, I can see that the page's source contains the following HTML structure:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <caption />
            <thead />
            <tbody />
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I programatically download the page's source using HtmlUnitDriver, then use driver.getPageSource(), I see that the corresponding HTML structure has changed to:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <caption />
        <tbody />
    </table>
</div>
```

1. Why does the HtmlUnitDriver's report differ to that given by Firebug?
2. Can I set up firebug so that I can inspect the HTML structure according to how the HtmlUnitDriver will report it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Firebug does not adjust the HTML structure that way, i.e. the integrated developer tools should show you the same.

I assume the second wrapping `<div>` and the `<thead>` get added by some JavaScript running on the page.

You can check that by disabling JavaScript, e.g. by going to [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) and setting `javascript.enabled` to `false` or via an add-on like NoScript or Ghostery.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment - I was away from my computer for a couple of days. I disabled the JavaScript, then inspected the page's HTML using Firebug, which then turned out to be the same as the HtmlUnitDriver's report. Many thanks!